# How to create 2D H5Array in HDF5DotNet

Tags: c#, hdf5

I'm investigating using HDF5 with C# and Matlab/Octave for my data storage.  I have a rather basic problem at the moment... I can create and save a 1D dataset in an h5 file, but can't fathom out the code for a 2D one:

My 2-D matrix (from a list of lists)

```
List<List<int>> table = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> row;
        for (int a=1;a<13;a++)
        {
            row = new List<int>();
            for (int b=1;b<13;b++)
                row.Add(a*b);
            table.Add(row);
        }
// Require an array containing dimensions of array to store.  
            long[] dims = new long[2];
            dims[0] = table.Count;
            dims[1]=table[0].Count;

            int[][] arrays = table.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

So far so good.  Now, to create the HDF5 file...

```
H5DataSpaceId spaceId = H5S.create_simple(1, dims);
H5DataTypeId typeId = H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT);
H5DataSetId dset = H5D.create(h5fileid, "TimesTables", typeId, spaceId);
```

Now, the following line I used successfully for a 1-D array, but I can't find the syntax for a 2-D array...

```
H5D.write(dset,typeId,new H5Array<int>(arrays));
```

My second question is how do you create groups, and groups of groups?  As yet I've not begun to work on that, but I'd appreciate a starting point while I continue to work on the first bit!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that if you define your dataset in C# using `data[a,b]` notation instead of `data[a][b]` notation, the `H5D.write()` call just works as written.  So,

```
var mydata = new int[100,100];   // int[100][100] doesn't work
...
H5D.write(dset,typeId,new H5Array<int>(mydata));
```